# Oracle Insert all data from another table contain duplicates how to avoid

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

have two tables A and B both same structure except B has one addition extra column inserting as "null". I need to Retain all data from A in B when I insert like below query it is inserting duplicate values because of that getting "primary Key violation error" when I try to create the "CONSTRAINT PK_Details_A PRIMARY KEY" Please help on this to avoid duplicate values while inserting the records.
Thanks in advance.

```
Insert into tableB(
         id,          effectiveDate, endDate
        ,startDate,   Type,          salary
        ,baseSalary,  Amount,        Amount1
        ,currency,    Percentage,    Salary
        ,Notional
       )
select   id,          effectiveDate, endDate
        ,startDate,   Type,          salary
        ,baseSalary,  Amount,        Amount1
        ,currency,    Percentage, Salary,null
  from tableA;
```

### EDIT

Primary key definition for `B` copied from comment below:

```
ALTER TABLE B
  ADD CONSTRAINT PK_B
    PRIMARY KEY ( oid)
      USING INDEX ( CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_B ON B ( oid )
```

Comment: simple answer: `select distinct ...`... but if you provide some data from your query and the destination table it will be useful... is it exception because there're duplicates in your query? or because some data with the IDs exist in TableB?

Comment: Table B is new table created so it is empty

Comment: What is the primary key in TABLEB?

Comment: Try merge statement [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

Comment: It doesn't appear that  you're copying `A.OID` to B. Is this an oversight? If it's not an oversight, how are values being populated into `B.OID`? Is there a trigger which does this?

Comment: yes trigger is doing this.

Comment: can you show the trigger? because if it's just insert new value into `oid` you shouldn't see the error. I suppose something is wrong with the trigger itself